# Pass parameters to prototype function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, prototype, affix

I'm tring to modify bootstrap 3 javascript adding a new function for affix plugin.
In particular I addded this function:

```
Affix.prototype.refresh = function (elem) {
  console.log("refresh");
  console.log(elem);
  this.options.offset.top = elem.offset.top;
}
```

my question is, witch is the syntax to call this function passing elem parameter?

I'm tring this:

```
$("#_mapDiv").affix("refresh",{offset:{top:100}});
```

but i have this output in my console:

```
refresh
undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offset' of undefined
```

Comment: Not sure I get it, are you trying to create a jQuery plugin ?

Comment: I think he is extending the `affix` lib with his `refresh` method.

Comment: Is that meant to have an uppercase `A` at the `Affix.prototype.refresh`?

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814201/passing-parameters-to-a-prototyped-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

It should be `affix.refresh(param)`.

Comment: no, i'm tring but this is the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object function (option)"